# PHP String Extraction

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm weak with regex, need help. My problem is I have to extract all the string that matches the given pattern I have into an array. See the problem below:

**The string**

```
<?php
$alert_types = array(
    'warning' => array('', __l("Warning!") ),
    'error' => array('alert-error', __l("Error!") ),
    'success' => array('alert-success', __l("Success!") ),
    'info' => array('alert-info', __l("For your information.") ),
);?>
```

**The Preg_Match Code**

```
preg_match("/.*[_][_][l][\(]['\"](.*)['\"][\)].*/", $content, $matches);
```

I'm only getting the first one match which is *Warning!*. I'm Expecting matches will have the following values:

```
Warning!, Error!, Success!, For your information.
```

Actually I'm using file_get_contents($file) to get the string.

Can anyone help me to solve this. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: sorry guys, I should used preg_match_all instead of preg_match

Comment: @mario yeah you're right. I've also solved the problem without looking on that possible duplicate. :) here's my regex: preg_match_all("|__l\(['\"](.*)['\"]\)|", $content, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER); incase for those interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match()` only finds the first match in the string.  Use `preg_match_all()` to get all matches.

```
preg_match_all("/.*__l\(['\"](.*?)['\"]\).*/", $content, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will contain an array of the strings you're looking for.

BTW, you don't need all those single-character brackets. Just put the character into the regexp.

```
var_dump($matches);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(45) "    'warning' => array('', __l("Warning!") ),"
    [1]=>
    string(52) "    'error' => array('alert-error', __l("Error!") ),"
    [2]=>
    string(58) "    'success' => array('alert-success', __l("Success!") ),"
    [3]=>
    string(65) "    'info' => array('alert-info', __l("For your information.") ),"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Warning!"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Error!"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Success!"
    [3]=>
    string(21) "For your information."
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I've done that, but there is something wrong again. I have this string: `sprintf(__l('You have %d on the cart right now. Want to %sview%s?'), $totalPrintCart, "<a hre='/'>","</a>")`, and the output is `You have %d on the cart right now. Want to %sview%s?') , $totalPrintCart, \"<a hre='\/'>\",\"<\/a>`. Do you know how to get exactly just `You have %d on the cart right now. Want to %sview%s?`

Comment: I've changed `(.*)` to `(.*?)` to make it non-greedy.